# HybridAuth getUserProfile returns Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, hybridauth

Well i'm using HybridAuth for google, FB and Twitter, and for FB works just fine, google returns empty user profile.

AccessToken is OK

getUserProfile() data is set NULL:

```
object(Hybrid_User)#8 (3) { ["providerId"]=> string(6) "Google" ["timestamp"]=> int(1452502079) ["profile"]=> object(Hybrid_User_Profile)#9 (22) { ["identifier"]=> NULL ["webSiteURL"]=> NULL ["profileURL"]=> NULL ["photoURL"]=> NULL ["displayName"]=> NULL ["description"]=> NULL ["firstName"]=> NULL ["lastName"]=> NULL ["gender"]=> NULL ["language"]=> NULL ["age"]=> NULL ["birthDay"]=> NULL ["birthMonth"]=> NULL ["birthYear"]=> NULL ["email"]=> NULL ["emailVerified"]=> NULL ["phone"]=> NULL ["address"]=> NULL ["country"]=> NULL ["region"]=> NULL ["city"]=> NULL ["zip"]=> NULL } } } }
```

Any idea what to check?

Comment: #CLOSED Ok it's fixed. It looks like Google+ API needs to be enabled in the project.

Answer (score 1):

just pointing for other user that experienced with same behaviour.
you can enable debug mode by adding parameters on config file, just like this

```
array(
    "base_url" => "", 
    "providers" => array (
        "Google" => array ( 
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys"    => array ( "id" => "", "secret" => "" )
        ),
        "Facebook" => array ( 
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys"    => array ( "id" => "", "secret" => "" )
        ),
        "Twitter" => array ( 
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys"    => array ( "key" => "", "secret" => "" ),
            "includeEmail" => true 
        ),
    ),

    // if you want to enable logging, set 'debug_mode' to true 
    "debug_mode" => false,
    // then provide a writable file by the web server on "debug_file"
    "debug_file" => "log.txt"
);
```

then you can check log, that's correct to use google user data we need to enable google+ api on google developer console,
and need to wait a while during propagation